# Classes in File Handling in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, class, binaryfiles, file-handling

I am getting this output in the interactive mode.

```
 class test:
        def p(self):
            print 'PP'

>>> f=open('E:\Python\Roy Progs\Test','w')
>>> t=test()
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dump(t,f)
>>> f.close()
>>> f=open('E:\Python\Roy Progs\Test','r')
>>> pickle.load(f).p()
PP
>>> f.close()
>>> 
=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>> f=open('E:\Python\Roy Progs\Test','r')
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.load(f).p()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.load(f).p()
  File "E:\Python\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "E:\Python\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "E:\Python\lib\pickle.py", line 1075, in load_inst
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "E:\Python\lib\pickle.py", line 1132, in find_class
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'
```

From the output I realize that the definition of the class (whose object is stored in the file) must be in there in the RAM at the time of retrieving data and using it. I however do not understand why this must be the case, by storing objects in the file am I not storing the class definition also?

Comment: Don't paste images of text - paste the text itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I hope its ok now.

Answer (score 1):

The pickle module stores classes by named reference. If you change the name or location of the class pickle will raise an error.

A quick illustration of that can be seen in the interactive:

```
>>> class test:
    x = 5


>>> from pickle import dumps
>>> dumps(test)
'c__main__\ntest\np0\n.' # pickle is storing a reference to 'test'
```

To successfully call load pickle must be able to find the previously defined class (which is destroyed when you call restart in idle)